# How to use ssh to transfer files from computer a to local computer

Tags: ssh, directory

I am trying to get some files off of my school Linux account using ssh. I have got the connection to work using:

`scp <school_server>: ~/folder I want ~/where I want to go`.

But when it goes to transfer folder it gives me the message:

`not a regular file`

The file contains .java files, and I want the whole folder.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To recursively copy a whole directory using scp, you need to add the `-r` switch

```
scp -r remotehost:/path/to/remote/dir/ /path/to/local/dir/
```

Comment: worked perfectly, thanks for the quick response

Answer (score 1):

I have destination that needs PEM to connect and it also has different SSH port. This worked for me like charm:

For e.g. Copy folder (and subfolders) from `sourceserver` to `targetserver`, run this on `sourceserver`

```
$ rsync -azu -e 'ssh -i ./pem_for_target_server.pem -p <port_number_for_target_server>' /folder/path/on/source username_on_target@target.server.name:/path/on/target/where/you/want/to/copy/folder/on/source/
```

(In case you get `permissions are too open` for pem file, run this:
`chmod 400 ./pem_for_target_server.pem`)