# Copy folders (not one file) using SSH ubuntu?

Tags: ssh, directory, scp

I am trying to copy a folder to remote Ubuntu server using command line ssh connection, i understand it's doable to transfer a file using scp but i have many files in a folder iam trying to copy to that remote server, how is that done? anyone? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 226, accepted):

You can use secure copy (scp) with the recursive option (`-r`):

```
scp -r /path/to/local/dir user@remotehost:/path/to/remote/dir
```

Alternatively, I recommend rsync because you can resume transfers if the connection breaks, and it intelligently transfers only the differences between files:

```
rsync -avz -e 'ssh' /path/to/local/dir user@remotehost:/path/to/remote/dir
```

---

Note that in both cases you should be careful of trailing slashes: moving `/path/to/local/dir` to `remotehost:/path/to/remote/dir/` results in `/path/to/remote/dir/dir`

Comment: Won't it ask for remote machine's password? I tried the above command and got `Host key verification failed.
`

Comment: Depends on the ssh server setup, but generally yes, it will use a key to authenticate and fallback to password if it's allowed.

Comment: This is seriously slow. Any better /much faster alternatives?

Comment: Much much faster approach is here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/10037/66602

Comment: Sure. If you compress things first then only rsync the tarball (and later decompress) then it could be faster. This doesn’t change the core answer.

Comment: rsync command given here just kept waiting for me. For me, [this worked like charm](https://askubuntu.com/a/1227536/1009148)

Comment: I have my ssh private key, how can I use it with `scp`?

Comment: It would be great to have an extended answer because it is not clear what must be running on a second machine, and how to get `user@remotehost`.

Comment: the question and answer assume SSH is already setup for the two machines. how to setup ssh access is a separate question and there are plenty of tutorials etc. to answer that, e.g., https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Configuring and https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/ssh-essentials-working-with-ssh-servers-clients-and-keys