# `scp -r` wont copy the directory I've selected in winows

Tags: server, windows-10, scp

I'm attempting to copy my desktop folder `excelsite` using `scp -r`. The folder is a django website. The command ive used is `scp -r excelsite ***@***.***.***` (and yes, I was cd'd into the desktop). When running the command everything seems to be working since its copying stuff. But not the folder `excelsite`. The command line looks like this:

```
db.sqlite3                | 144 kB | 144.0 kB/s | ETA: 00:00:00 | 100%
abstract.h                | 30 kB |  30.4 kB/s | ETA: 00:00:00 | 100%
asdl.h                    | 1 kB |   1.2 kB/s | ETA: 00:00:00 | 100%
ast.h                     | 0 kB |   1.0 kB/s | ETA: 00:00:00 | 100%
bitset.h                  | 0 kB |   0.5 kB/s | ETA: 00:00:00 | 100%
bltinmodule.h             | 0 kB |   0.3 kB/s | ETA: 00:00:00 | 100%
```

I have no clue what *abstract.h* is. Neither do I know what *asdl.h* is, etc. Its copying random stuff. And if that seems weird if, if just let it copy all of it, at some point it starts copying city names. Yes, CITY NAMES! I have noo clue whats going on. But one thing is for sure, it's not copying my directory.

Answer (score 0):

You must specify the destination path :

```
scp -r /local/path user@host:/remote/path
```

note that spaces in remote pathname must be escaped

```
scp -r /local/path user@host:/remote/path\\\ name
scp -r /local/path user@host:"'/remote/path name'"
```

---

You may also use **rsync** via ssh

```
rsync --stats -avzhe ssh /source/path user@host:/dest/path
```

More information:
 - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/rsync
 - https://askubuntu.com/a/446726/77093

Comment: still the same behaviour

Comment: Do you know why it might be copying this?

```db.sqlite3                | 144 kB | 144.0 kB/s | ETA: 00:00:00 | 100%
abstract.h                | 30 kB |  30.4 kB/s | ETA: 00:00:00 | 100%
asdl.h                    | 1 kB |   1.2 kB/s | ETA: 00:00:00 | 100%
ast.h                     | 0 kB |   1.0 kB/s | ETA: 00:00:00 | 100%
bitset.h                  | 0 kB |   0.5 kB/s | ETA: 00:00:00 | 100%
bltinmodule.h             | 0 kB |   0.3 kB/s | ETA: 00:00:00 | 100%
boolobject.h              | 0 kB |   0.9 kB/s | ETA: 00:00:00 | 100%
```

Comment: its copying .h files

Comment: if i try copying a file it works perfetly, but when copying a folder, it makes a mess

Comment: @ErikHolstV Holst see edited answer, you may use rsync via ssh (as i personally prefer) - Dont forget to specify (full) pathnames