# "cp: failed to access ‘user@remote/home/file’: Not a directory" when copying a file over ssh, using cp file user@remove syntax

Tags: ssh

I am trying to copy a file over from my machine to my personal space on a university server. On my machine, the file is located at `/home/karnivaurus/file.pdf`.

If I connect to the server with `ssh karnivaurus@server.uni.ac.uk`, and then run `pwd`, it prints `/homes/karnivaurus`. If I run `ls`, it just displays one directory, `foo`.  What I want to do then, is to copy this file over to the directory `/homes/karnivaurus/foo`.

So, after exiting the ssh, I enter the local home directory `/home/karnivaurus`. I then run the command `cp paper.pdf karnivaurus@server.uni.ac.uk/foo/paper.pdf`, but this returns the error message `cp: failed to access ‘karnivaurus@shell1.doc.ic.ac.uk/homes/karnivaurus/paper.pdf’: Not a directory`. I have also tried running `cp paper.pdf karnivaurus@server.uni.ac.uk/homes/karnivaurus/foo/paper.pdf`, but this gives me the same error message.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `scp paper.pdf karnivaurus@server.uni.ac.uk/foo/`   `cp` is a local copy operation.  `scp` is for performing a `cp` over `ssh`.

Comment: @user4556274 You forgot the `:` in the command.  It would be `scp paper.pdf karnivaurus@server.uni.ac.uk:/foo/`

Comment: Aye.  I copy-pasted the destination from the question without looking closely enough.  Thanks.

Comment: OP, please don't crosspost.

Comment: Related http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/188289/68757

Comment: Possible duplicate of [copy files over ssh](http://askubuntu.com/questions/646443/copy-files-over-ssh)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use `scp`

```
DESCRIPTION
     scp copies files between hosts on a network.  It uses ssh(1) for data
     transfer, and uses the same authentication and provides the same security
     as ssh(1).
```

The basic syntax is essentially the same as that of `cp`

```
scp paper.pdf karnivaurus@server.uni.ac.uk:/homes/karnivaurus/foo/
```

or

```
scp paper.pdf karnivaurus@server.uni.ac.uk:~/foo/
```

Answer (score 14):

Some other ways to transfer files when you have `ssh` access:

- `rsync`:

  ```
  rsync -av paper.pdf karnivaurus@server.uni.ac.uk:/where/to/put/
  ```

  replace `/where/to/put/` with your desired directory name, it can be a filename too if you want to rename the file on the remote host given the intermediate directories exist.

  `rsync` has a big advantage over `scp` that it uses the delta transfer algorithm, so if for some reason the transfer halted in the middle, you can resume the transfer from that place again using `rsync`.
- Direct `ssh`:

  ```
  ssh karnivaurus@server.uni.ac.uk 'cat >/where/to/put/paper.pdf' <paper.pdf
  ```

  Here transferring the file with direct `ssh`, sending the input file on STDIN of `ssh`, which is forwarded to the remote command and running the command `cat >/where/to/put/paper.pdf` on the remote host. After operation the file will be available as `/where/to/put/paper.pdf` on `server.uni.ac.uk`, change the path to meet your need.